# PHP flush loop with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Sorry for duplicate question, but the given answers do not work for me.

So far I use Ajax to execute PHP after a button click and ob_flush() to flush out the echo() one after each other. However I see my echos coming all at once nevertheless. Below is my code:

PHP:

```
ob_start();
echo "Server received this information from user: ". $debugMode. "<br>";
echo "Server answers this: <br>";
ob_flush();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) 
{
  echo( "Hello World ". $i. "<br>" );
  ob_flush();
  usleep(200000); //wait 0.2 seconds
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

AJAX:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function runAjax(debugMode)
    {
        if (debugMode=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("outputPhp").innerHTML="nothing was send to server";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // AJAX use with IE7+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // AJAX use with IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("outputPhp").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","TestButtonClick.php?q="+debugMode,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
<title>Debug</title>
</head>

<body>
<br>
<input type="button" size="10" value="test" 
onclick="runAjax(this.value)"/>
<span id="test">Click this button to run all tests</span>
<br>
<br>
<p id="outputPhp"></p>
<br>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your help!
Peter

Comment: did you checked if your PHP code shows the output while executing? if yes, then you can focus on the JavaScript.

Comment: PHP code does not flush when called itself. I guess I must look within the PHP code then. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: It should coming all at once since you make a sleep time in your php code, you have to delete the for loop from your php file and just `echo( "Hello World ". $i. "<br>" );`. Send the `$i` parameter from ajax, and make the sleep time in javascript i.e. call ajax 10 times with 0.2s delay

Comment: just use `ob_flush();` after `echo` and remove `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php

implicit-flush will help you.

And, you modify 'xmlhttp.readyState==4' to 'xmlhttp.readyState==3'

Comment: Thank you. as a fun fact: i needed both ob_implicit_flush(); at the beginning and ob_flush(); after each echo(); but now it is working.

Comment: It also turns out that I needed (xmlhttp.readyState==4 || xmlhttp.readyState== 3) otherwise my last echos would not be shown.